# Disable SSH agent with command line option

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

How can I tell ssh with a command line option to not use the SSH agent?

`ssh -a` does something different. It does not forward the agent, but uses it.

I read the man page, and could not find a solution.

Unsetting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` would work, but a command line option would be much better in my context.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can force `ssh` to use anything else than a SSH key to authenticate (e.g. password) with

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no ...
```

this way of course the agent will be ineffective. If you want to use a key, you can also specify it explicitly and ssh will only use that key and not all that are in the agent:

```
ssh -i path/to/id_rsa -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -F /dev/null ...
```

You mentioned `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. You can unset it just in the context of your `ssh` command like this:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh ...
```

Note the space after `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`. This way your are sure that the agent is not used while at the same time not modifying your working environment.

Comment: For me, `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` was not enough, because some other identity file was being used. I also added `-F /dev/null` to have no other configuration.

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question, but the correct answer to "How can I tell ssh with a command line option to not use the SSH-Agent?" hasn't been given yet:

- use the `-o IdentityAgent=none` option

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html (emphasis added):

> IdentityAgent
>
> Specifies the UNIX-domain socket used to communicate with the authentication agent.
>
> This option overrides the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable and can be used to select a specific agent. **Setting the socket name to none disables the use of an authentication agent**. ...

Comment: I had to use the same syntax to disable a ProxyCommand setting for a single host that otherwise would have used it.  Using "none" seems to be a magic word inside ssh.  In my case:   ssh $HOST -o ProxyCommand=none